# How to add a file name to a content value image android java

Tags: java, android

When a image is saved using the following code, the filename of the image is kinda random... How can i add a custom filename ?

This is my code:

```
            OutputStream outstream;
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Image");
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
            Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            outstream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outstream);
            outstream.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: There is .DISPLAY_NAME for that.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! @blackapps